# Admob Banner misplaced position

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, admob

I am trying to fit an Admob Banner on top of the navigation bar; I tried to use bottomNavigationBar inside that page, which works perfectly fine with a button:

[image: Desired Banner Position]

Now, when I replace that button with Admob Banner, the placement of the ad is over the actual navigation bar instead of on top of it.

[image: Ad Banner placed over Navigationbar]

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bloc.fetchLikedNews();
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Bookmarks', 
                  style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                  ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                  : Colors.white),
                      ),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                    ? Colors.grey[850]
                          : Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: scrollControllerLikedList,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(

          ),

          streamBuilder(bloc.likeNews),

        ],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17.0),
          child: AdmobBanner(
            adUnitId: getBannerAdUnitId(),
            adSize: AdmobBannerSize.BANNER,
          )
          ),
        ),
    ); 

  }


@override
  void initState() {
    scrollControllerLikedList = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 84);

  FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: getAppId());
    //Change appId With Admob Id
    _bannerAd = createBannerAd()
      ..load()
      ..show();
    super.initState();


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A known limitation of the firebase_admob plugin is that you cannot place the ad in a container only anchor it.

You can anchor it to the top to get close to what you are after using the parameters in the show():

```
    bannerAd
      ..show(
        anchorOffset: 60.0,
        anchorType: AnchorType.top,
      );
```

Alternatively, you can use this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter

Comment: That worked with AnchorType.bottom and Offset: 50.0 - Thank you for the answer :)